Save Mail Attachment to the disk using AE.Net IMAP
Im using open source Library AE.Net and trying to save email attachment to the disk of my PC, but method I use is not working. How to save attachment from email via IMAP protocol?
My method is:
ImapClient ic = new ImapClient("imap.yandex.com", "username", "password", AE.Net.Mail.AuthMethods.Login, 993, true);
 ic.SelectMailbox("INBOX");
 Console.WriteLine(ic.GetMessageCount());
AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage[] mm = ic.GetMessages(0, 10);
foreach (AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage m in mm)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Subject);
       foreach (AE.Net.Mail.Attachment att in m.Attachments)
    {
        att.Save(@"D:\test\savedattachementsfromYandexIMAP" + Path.GetExtension(att.Filename));
    }
}

Program executing without any error, but no attachments saved to folder.
Does any one faced with same issue? Please advise how to fix that.

Have you inspected anything with your debugger?

What does Console.WriteLine(ic.GetMessageCount()); show? How many messages does mm contain? How many attachments do each of those messages contain?

@mxmissile
i ve inspected program with the debugger, when it checks email with attachment in the INBOX, it doesn't see any attachment.

@phuzi
Yes, Console.WriteLine(ic.GetMessageCount()) ;   shows how many messages in the INBOX.  Issue is that program see messages but dont see attachments inside the messages.

In that case you should focus on figuring out what you actually get back from GetMessages(int startIndex, int endIndex, bool headersonly = true, bool setseen = false).  May be take a look at the other options that are present on that method.
